# Is there a built-in Pandas function to perform a "first greater or equal" slicing of the dataframe on an index?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to return the first row of a dataframe for which the index is greater or equal to an input value.

My solution is pretty slow and not elegant at all, I wondered if there is a built-in function that would do so, or even a more efficient way to do what I am doing?

Obviously a way to speed up would be to remove the sorting from the function and make sure that my dataframe is sorted prior to calling the function.

```
def greater_or_equal(dframe, index_value):
    df_temp = dframe.sort_index()
    try:
        return df_temp.loc[df_temp.index[df_temp.index>=index_value][0]]
    except:
        print('No value greater or equal than input value')
        return None

df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.to_datetime(['01-07-2021', '02-03-2021','01-01-2021']), columns = ['foo', 'bar'], data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])


greater_or_equal(df, pd.to_datetime('12-25-2020'))
Out[9]: 
foo    5
bar    6
Name: 2021-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: int64

greater_or_equal(df, pd.to_datetime('01-08-2021'))
Out[10]: 
foo    3
bar    4
Name: 2021-02-03 00:00:00, dtype: int64

greater_or_equal(df, pd.to_datetime('06-08-2021'))
Out[11]: 
No value greater or equal than input value
```

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in with `loc`:

```
def greater_or_equal(dframe, index_value):
    return dframe.loc[index_value:].head(1)

# string works just fine
greater_or_equal(df, '12-25-2020')
```

Output:

```
            foo  bar
2021-01-07    1    2
```

And

```
greater_or_equal(df, '06-08-2021')
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [foo, bar]
Index: []
```

Comment: interesting, thanks! I wonder why it works if I pas a string, but not if I pass a pd.Timestamp to the function. Even though the index of my dataframe is a DatetimeIndex

Comment: @ylnor I think it's just the design decision, slicing with strings on datetime index allows , while slicing with datetime on datetime index will look for exact date. Take it with a grain of salt. More details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html).